# Validating and saving related models together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 related models and I need to validate and create them together.

**Application**

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :application_sessions, inverse_of: :application
```

**ApplicationsSession**

```
class ApplicationSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :application, inverse_of: :application_sessions
```

1. If it was possible I'd like to create an `Application` through an `ApplicationSession` but`application_session.build_application` won't work because it will never be a valid record.
2. `application_session.create_application` wont work either because even if `ApplicationSession` is not a valid record, it will create an `Application`.

For the first one; it validates `Application` and `ApplicationSession`. This logic might work fine if I only skip `application_id` validation for `ApplicationSession` if when `Application` is a valid record. Still I prefer to use a more elegant solution if there is any.

For the second one; I can delete the `Application` afterwards if `ApplicationSession` is not a valid record but I didn't quite like this solution.

What is best approach to create/not to create those dependent records together with Rails?

**Clarification:**

Simply, I want the parent and child to be created together while there is no parent exists and a valid child about to save *(valid expect it does not have any parent)*. If child is not a valid record, nothing should be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using new and build would work.

```
application = Application.new({attr1: val1, attr2: val2 ..})
application.application_sessions.build({attr1: val1, attr2: val2 ..})
application.save
```

In this way, if application is invalid, application and its new application_session would not be saved. The same goes if the application_session is invalid.

In terminal where you fired-up your `rails console` command, you would see something like:

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

If application and its new application_session are both valid, both would be saved :)

Answer (score 0):

From a data modelling point of view I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

I think you have a parent/child relationship where the parent is optional?

If you create a parent and then delete it you will have dangling keys in the child that point to nothing, be far better to just have nulls in there.

Is there any reason you can't just call new or create with a null parent id? Is the parent key mandatory? If so turn off the mandatory requirement and it should work. Build only works from parent to child, not the other way round when all the keys are null. I think you have to call save on the parent and the children are saved once the parent ID is known.

If the parent must exist for your app to work create a dummy one and have all the children you don't want to have a specific parent belonging to it, then you can easily find them again. Without knowing the flow of your app I'm not sure what else I could advise.

Comment: Existence of parent is a must. The thing is; parent has to be exists only if the first created child is valid. Therefore I need to validate child before I create a parent; if it is possible. But you can not do that because child will always be an invalid record unless there is a parent.

Comment: In which case ... use a transaction :) Roll it back if the child is invalid.

Comment: Transactions worked but probably they are not the best solution for this kind of problems. Furthermore controllers became to complicated. I implement the first solution and tests say they are doing just fine and codes are more readable. Still I would be happier if there was a simpler and non-hacky solution.

Comment: You're trying to do something that *is* hacky and a bit unusual :-). I'd move the transaction out of the controller. This kind of complexity belongs in the model.